# how to find jenkins systems through google search that are accessible for remote control?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins, scripting, google-search

Good day!
I have a chance to get a job in my dream company. Before i could proceed to interview i have to finish test. 
One of the question is really confusing for me:

**-1. Write a script in Python, which uses the google search to find Jenkins systems that are available to be managed anonymously. 
2. List the risks of accessibility of such a system from the Internet.**

Guys, any of your suggestions or recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: What confuses you about which of the two tasks you listed?

Comment: Question 1. Dan, do you have any idea?

Comment: Break it up into smaller problems. Start with figuring out how to manually find Jenkins instances. Maybe set up a local copy of one, and familiarize yourself a little with it (esp. administration). I'd guess there will be some page that's accessible only when anonymous management is enabled. Once you can do it by hand, automate it with Python.

Comment: Seems you're not right for the position ;-)

Comment: Good luck btw. Google shouldn't contain any Jenkins instances because of their `robots.txt`.

Comment: @DanMašek thank you.

Comment: @StephenKing might be you are right :)